# Usage of defparameter

Tags: global-variables, lisp, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop

I wonder if it is because i do no understand something about the core of the defparameter macro.

So, this gives a weird mistake. I start with:

```
(defparameter *x* #(1 4 7))
(defparameter *y* #(2 3 55))
```

Everything's fine but then this:

```
(defparameter *res* (make-array * :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0))
```

gives a mistake, which I do not get at all:

```
 The value                                                                       
 *Y*                                                                           
 is not of type                                                                  
 (OR (MOD 4611686018427387901) CONS NULL)                                      
 when binding SB-VM::DIMENSIONS
    [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` evaluates to the last evaluated value, which is <s>that of</s> the symbol `*Y*`<s>, which is an array `#(2 3 55)`</s>.

But [`make-array`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_ar.htm) expects its first argument to specify "dimensions" of the array *it* creates:

> **make-array** *dimensions &key element-type initial-element initial-contents
>
> adjustable fill-pointer displaced-to displaced-index-offset*
>
> => *new-array*
>
> **Arguments and Values:**
>
> dimensions---a *designator* for a *list* of *valid array dimensions*.

### ... a ***list***.

(emphasis mine). Some lists are `null`s, some are `cons`es. But not <s>arrays</s> symbols.

And since it expects a list [*designator*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_l.htm#list_designator), i.e.

> a *non-nil atom* (denoting a *singleton list* whose *element* is that *non-nil atom*) or a *proper list* (denoting itself),

the other possibility is a whole number.

Comment: * evaluates to the last evaluate value.

This I didn't know. Thanks! Changed it to 0, became way better.

Comment: there's also **, and ***; and +, ++, +++. see http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v__stst_.htm and  http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pl_plp.htm, http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v__.htm, and http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_sl_sls.htm.

Comment: `*y*` is a symbol, not an array (which happens to be the value of that symbol).

Comment: @RainerJoswig that will teach me not to answer without testing (hopefully). thanks! (the end result is the same, it is not a list -- nor a number ;) )

Comment: That's important, because it helps to understand the error message. The error message really means the symbol `*y*`.

Comment: if it were the array, the error message would have been exactly the same though.

Comment: @WillNess: it would be *the value #(1 2 3) is not of...*

Comment: @RainerJoswig you're right. It says so right there: "The value `*Y*`"... d'oh! thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

```
CL-USER 28 > (defparameter *y* #(2 3 55))
*Y*

CL-USER 29 > *
*Y*
```

The value of `*` is the first value of the last top-level evaluation result.

In your case the value is `*y*` - a symbol. Then you call `MAKE-ARRAY` with that symbol as the first argument. `MAKE-ARRAY` does not expect a symbol - thus the error:

```
The value                                                                       
 *Y*                                                                           
 is not of type                                                                  
 (OR (MOD 4611686018427387901) CONS NULL)                                      
 when binding SB-VM::DIMENSIONS
    [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

The error means this: the symbol `*y*` is neither a number (with a certain maximum size) nor a list. Remember `*y*` was the result of evaluating `*`.

Comment: is it a bug in CLHS, about single number being also accepted there? the wording seems to exclude it, yet the examples at the bottom of that page include such use.

Comment: @WillNess: no, it says *a designator for a list...* . A single number is a designator for a list with this one number. See *list designator* in the glossary. You'll find the concept of *designators* in many places in Common Lisp.

Comment: Yes I did try to do that, but I couldn't see there anything about list designators specifically, none through the clicking around anyway. indeed "list designator" is that entry; had to find it manually.

Comment: @WillNess: right, it would be more helpful if 'designator for a list' would have  mentioned and linked 'list designator'. Thus you have to manually put the type in front of 'designator'. For example: string designator, list designator, ...

Comment: here's that non-linked [glossary entry](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_l.htm#list_designator). to whom it may concern.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the [`mod`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_mod.htm) in the error message, that is a type specifier: `(mod 4611686018427387901)` means "an integer between 0 and 4611...", the big number being the [`array-dimension-limit`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_ar_dim.htm).